# Is there a bug in ASP.Net MVC 2 RC version for UpdateModel()?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to implement MVC 2 RC version, the latest release of ASP.Net MVC and it can't do a simple Controller.UpdateModel(object) without throwing this exception:

The model of type '[Insert namespace of object being updated here]' could not be updated.

InvalidOperationException

Here's the stack trace:

at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model, String prefix, String[] includeProperties, String[] excludeProperties, IValueProvider valueProvider)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.UpdateModel[TModel](TModel model)
   at Ccis.Cgov360.Web.InternalApp.Controllers.AdminController.MailingLabelTypeSelected() in C:\Projects\Meadowlark\Development\Meadowlark\Applications\InternalApp\Controllers\AdminController.cs:line 1528
   at lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__a()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)

When I use MVC Preview 2 it functions and updates the model just fine with no exceptions thrown. I saw elsewhere that there is a bug in RC version, is this the same thing?

I've spent way too much time trying to fix this issue. I was hoping to get the RC release so that we can start using the Html helpers such as TextBoxFor<>, CheckBoxFor<>, etc. and the client-side validation.

Comment: Normally this means that validation failed and that the model is invalid.  What is the value of ModelState.IsValid?  If this is false, look through the entries in that dictionary to see what the error was.

Comment: @Levi were this an answer I'd upvote it!

Comment: Thank you Levi, you just gave me the next clue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also ran into this issue.

As a work-around, I am just calling TryUpdateModel() instead of UpdateModel().

Answer (score 3):

To add to Levi's comment, if you catch the exception and return the Edit view, you should see the validation message for the field(s) failing validation, assuming your view contains:

```
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name) %>
```

And your Controller Edit action would contain...

```
     try {
         UpdateModel(entity, new [] {  "name", "address1", "address2", "city", "state", "zip" } );
         TempData["Message"] = "Success";
         return RedirectToAction("List");
     }
     catch {
         TempData["Message"] = "Error saving form";
         return View(entity);
     }
```